# Windows phone - Is there a away to see my app usage?

Tags: windows-phone

In the devCenter I can see how many people had downloaded my app, but I can't see how many of them use my app, daily, weekly, how long in a day etc.

Is there a way to get this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using an analytics framework, but you have to integrate one into your app during development.

There are various analytics frameworks available, such as [Google Analytics](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/105089), [PreEmptive Solutions](http://www.preemptive.com/know-more/mobile), [Bango Analytics](http://bango.com/mobileappanalytics/), [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html), and so on and so forth.